# How to set a default value in antd datepicker with date-fns

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd, date-fns

I have replaced moment with date-fns for date-picker using this [guide](https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment). But I am not able to set the default value in the date-picker with date-fns.

It is done with momentjs in the following way but I can't figure out how to do this with date-fns

```
const dateFormat = 'YYYY/MM/DD';
<DatePicker defaultValue={moment('2015/01/01', dateFormat)} format={dateFormat} />
```

Comment: You would use [parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/parse). `parse('2015/01/01', dateFormat, new Date())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After including the packages from the guide you linked to you would use the date-fns [`parse()`](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/parse) method. You will need to update your `dateFormat` to `'yyyy/mm/dd'`.

```
const dateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd";

<DatePicker
   defaultValue={parse("2015/01/22", dateFormat, new Date())}
   format={dateFormat}
/>
```

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cszk8)